# Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

For text validation for chars I am using like `[a-zA-z]` and for numbers like `[0-9]` ..if I need to add special symbols I am adding slash like `[a-zA-z/-/]`.

While including lot of symbols its getting difficult and my javascript is getting extremely big. Is there an easy way to do it ?

Regards
A.Collins

Comment: Note that `[A-z]` is equivalent to `[A-Z[\\\\]^_\`a-z]` so it does not only contain `A`–`Z` but also `a`–`z` and the characters `[`, `\‍`, `]`, `^`, `_` and `\`` that are between `Z` and `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/) cheat sheet. for instance, `[0-9]` can be reduced to `\d`.

Comment: Thanks npinti. Its very helpful

Answer (score 0):

For the general case of "a lot of characters" — no.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to escape characters. `\` is the correct escape character to be used:

```
[a-zA-Z\/]
```

You can use character classes, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` can be replaced by `[\w]`. The only characters that needs to be escaped are `\` and `-`. `^` should be escaped too when it's the first character in the character class.

Comment: He's adding a slash to his character class, not a hyphen.

Comment: In this case there are two reasons why the hyphen does not need to be escaped. It can not be interpreted as part of a character range because (1) the previous character already is part of a character range; (2) it is at the end of the character class.

Answer (score 0):

- `\w` for alphanumerics and underscores
- `\d` for digits
- `\s` for whitespace

You can mix them, resulting in stuff like, for example, `[\d.]` (for matching numbers & dots).

Answer (score 0):

In a character class, `x-y` means "all characters between `x` and `y`". If you just have one additional character, in your case `/` then you don't need to use the `x-y` format, you can just drop the character in:

```
[a-zA-z/]
```